# In which layer should I install Individual Authentication related packages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I am new at `Asp.Net MVC` and now I am trying create project with n-tier architecture. My application layers are as follows.

1. Project  -  Presentation View
2. Project.Core - Business Logic (Modal View and Repositories)
3. Project.DAL - Database Logic (DbContext and Application Modal)
4. Project.Test - Unit Testing Project

Now, I want to add `OAuth2` in my application. But, I am confused about installing packages for Individual Authentication in my solution.

So, my question is **In which Layer should I add `Identity.Owin` and `OAuth2` related packages?**

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **Project - Presentation View** layer. You controllers have to known if certain user is authenticated and authorized or no. If user is allowed then **Project.Core - Business Logic (Modal View and Repositories)** will be invoked by those controllers (you will probably inject those repositoried into controllers).

Answer (score 0):

There would be 2 option as per my opinion,

1- If your view interacting with controller then authentication would be in presentation view project.

2- And if you have Business layer like; WCF Or WebApi, in which you can directly

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I will prefer to add the OAuth2 lib in presentation level